# How to get combined image from matplotlib as variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an image and heatmap. I plot both of them with im_show

```py
axes_img1 = plt.imshow(255 * normalized_heat_map, alpha=alpha, cmap=cmap)
axes_img2 = plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Both `axes_img1` and `axes_img2` are only for image or heatmap, `plt.show()` displays image with heatmap, in the way I want.


How can I get image (typically matplotlib outputs `AxesImage` type) that represents what `plt.show()` displays without saving any files?

Comment: you could use `io.BytesIO` to create file-object in memory and save in this file

Comment: Can you give code sample that will retrieve the combined image?

Comment: Ok that worked  `buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='jpg')
    buf.seek(0)
    pil_image = Image.open(buf)`

Comment: But his solution is so slow compared to `pil_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(axes_img.get_cmap()(axes_img.get_array()) * 255))` Can it be done in similar manner but for combined image?

Comment: if you want only image without axis then you can combine `PIL` images. Create new images `new_image = Image.new((width, height))`  and paste other images `new_image.paste(other_image, position)`

Comment: if you have two arrays then you may create new array horizontally `np.hstack((image1, image2))` (or vertically with `np.vstack`)

Comment: Thanks solution with paste works, it's composing 2 images quickly

Answer (score 1):

`plt.show()` actually calls `canvas.draw()` and them shows the drawn (to buffer) image on the ui. hence, You need to call `canvas.draw()` and grab the buffer in numpy array.

```
def grab_buffer(fig):
    data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
    data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
    return data

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1) # 2 rows, 1 column
ax.flat[0].imshow(255 * normalized_heat_map, alpha=alpha, cmap=cmap)
ax.flat[1].imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
fig.canvas.draw()
img_as_numpy_array = grab_buffer(fig)
```

Comment: Maybe combined is misleading but that i mean that one image is on the top of another like you apply heapmap on the top of image